# Display ouput of AVL Tree traversals on multiple lines in JTextArea

Tags: java, tree-traversal

```
for(int i=0; i < list.length; i++)
{
    System.out.printf(" %2d",list[i]); // Formats right justified

    if ((i+1)%10==0)
    {
        System.out.println(); // Adds a new line after 10 values
    }
}
```

I'm trying to display the output of an AVL Tree inorder, preorder, and postorder traversals on multiple lines in the JTextArea(), preferably 10 numbers to a line. I tried it in the JTextArea() by adding 5 and 10 to the JTextArea() parameter (JTextArea(5, 10)), but it doesn't work. If so, how can the 'for' loop provided be altered to accomplish this? Thank you for all your help.

Comment: Sorry, friend, but where is the JTextArea? You are printing to System.out. Might this be the primary problem?

Comment: @xerx593 Here is the JTextArea: inorderTextArea = new JTextArea(5, 10);.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need something like an (efficient) "string aggregating object":

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();//before your loop
```

(String + String + String ..is considered ineffcient, but also possible)

In your loop, you populate `sb`:

```
for (int i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
    sb.append(String.format(" %2d", list[i])); // Formats right justified
    if ((i + 1) % 10 == 0) {
        sb.append(System.lineSeparator()); // Adds a new line (windows or unix like) after 10 values
    }
}
```

(@see [StringBuilder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html), [String.format](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object...-), [System.lineSeparator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#lineSeparator--))

And after that you can set the text of the TextArea like:

```
myJTextArea.setText(sb.toString());
```

Comment: I'm using Java programming language, I can't use 'append.'

Comment: Disregard my last comment, I can use 'append()' with the StringBuilder class. Thank you!

Comment: How can I use 'myJTextArea.setText(sb.toString());' to work with inorderTextArea.setText(AVLTree.inorderTraversal);? I tried inorderTextArea.setText(sb.toString(AVLTree.inorderTraversal)); but I'm getting a compile error.

Comment: Assume `myJTextArea == yourTextArea` :-) (any of the 3!?), and consider `return sb.toString();` in each of your "xOrderTraversal" (as the last/return statement).